# How to pre-process .csv files on integer values with cmd and fread from data.table

Tags: r, data.table, printf, fread

I have simulated data stored locally which I read into a list with `lapply` and `fread` and then work from the list thereafter. All files are equal in dimensions and format. I am wondering how I can improve the efficiency of reading time by using the `cmd` argument of `fread`.

For example, if I am interested in certain variables the `select` argument comes handy. The `nrows` argument is helpful when data from a specific year only is needed by first identifying the rows that include the years less than and equal to the year of interest and then filtering afterwards.

Having come across this [article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-data-tables-fread-can-save-you-a-lot-of-time-and-memory-and-take-input-from-shell-commands/) I have realised that the reading of files can be further optimised. However, I don't understand how to use the `sprintf` function since I want to preprocess on an integer value (the year in my case) rather than a string. Maybe using `lapply` creates a problem too (?).

If someone could please help on preprocessing multiple files (subsetting by an integer value and selecting desired variables) with `fread` and the `cmd` argument it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a MWE of my approach:

```
keepRows <- min(which(df$year > 3)) - 1
all.df <- lapply(seq_along(dataFiles), function(x){
  x <- fread(dataFiles[x], select = c("year", "a", "c", "e"),
             nrows = keepRows) #,
  x <- filter(x, year == 3)
})
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1:6, each = 3),
                 a = sample(20:25, 18, replace = TRUE),
                 b = rnorm(18, 1),
                 c = rbinom(18, 30, 0.25),
                 d = sample(letters, 18),
                 e = paste0(sample(letters, 18), sample(1:3, 18, replace = TRUE)))

dataFiles <- paste0("df", 1:5, ".csv")
```

Comment: Do your CSV files have column names?

Comment: In your case maybe awk would be better within cmd, something like: `fread(cmd = "awk -F, '$1 == 3' input.txt")`

Comment: Yes they do @zx8754

Comment: @zx8754 can you please explain what -F and input.txt represent?

Comment: what operating system are you running?

Comment: I am running a 64-bit OS  @Wimpel

Comment: windows, unix, ... ?

Comment: Sorry, Windows 10

Comment: Oh, awk won't work for Windows.

Comment: Ah pity, I was busy testing your answer. Any alternative for Windows?

Comment: yes.. `findstr` is windows (limited) version to do this

Comment: rather than using windows stuff it is better to just install linux-like environment for windows and use `awk` instead

Answer (score 2):

We can use *awk* within *cmd* (not tested):

```
library(data.table)

myCols <- c("year", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
mySelect <- c("year", "a", "c", "e")
myYear <- 3
ixCol <- match(mySelect, myCols)

all.df <- lapply(list.files("path/to/files/", pattern = "*.csv"), function(x){
  myCmd <- paste0("awk -F, '$1 == ", myYear, "' ", x)
  fread(cmd = myCmd, select = ixCol, col.names = myCols[ ixCol ])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my go at things using the findstr-command in Window 10

What it does: It builds a command that lookes for all line sthat start with the string `3,`, `4,`,`5,`,`6,`,`7,`,`8,` or `9,`, and passes these results to fread.

it needs the full path to your csv-files.. relative wo'nt work.. You will also have to use gsub to get windows-readable filenames

```
#what files to read?
files.to.read <- list.files( path = "C:/Users/your/Documents/here/temp", pattern = "^df[1-5]\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE )
#read files, only line stat start with regex "^[3-9],"
pattern = "^[3-9],"
data.table::rbindlist(
  lapply( files.to.read, function(x) {
        data.table::fread( cmd =  paste0( 'findstr /R "', pattern, '" ',  gsub( "\\/", "\\\\", x ) ), 
                           sep = ",", 
                           header = FALSE )
  }),
  use.names = TRUE, idcol = "from_df" )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get FINDSTR: Cannot open 'path'. I have taken your code as it is and only changed the path. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: guessing here: perhaps the whitespace in `2020-06-26 18-20`  is causing trouble?

Comment: then open the windows commandprompt, go to the folder `D:/Backup/PhD/Modelling/RQ1/Results/Calibration/2020-06-26 18-20/` and see what output you get from the command `findstr /R "^[3-9]," MySimCows_1.csv` (or whatever regex you need)... tweak the command until your output is correct, and then take it back into R..

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I have tried but it now starts to get a little out of my league.

Comment: my approach would be: Inside the windows-commandprompt try to get the findstr-command to return correct output for one file.. If this works, copy the command into R, and see if you can use fread to read the output. If this is also working, make it dynamic..

Comment: Yes I understand, but I don't know where to start in writing a findstr-command to return correct output for one file. I think that something that differs in my original data set with the MWE I gave is that the variable year is not the first column and is rather third to last. Perhaps this is one of the reasons it is not working; my understanding that one of the findstr functions is that it searches for a line beginning with 'pattern'.

Comment: `findstr /R ` looks for a regex-pattern on a line. The regex does not have to be at the start of a line (unless you say it should be, using  `^`.. more infor on regex: regex101.com

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help. Will do some more reading up on it.

Comment: Ah by simply removing ^ from `^[3-9]` it works. Can I specify a column for findstr to search?

Comment: Support for special characters in the regex is very limited in `findstr`... So you'll have to create a pretty dumb regex, like this: `pattern =  "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*,[a-zA-Z0-9]*,[3-6]"` will work if you want your third column-value (the  value after the second comma) tot start wite a 3, 4, or 6. Note that this will only work when your first and second column contain alhanumeric characters only...

Comment: Great, again thanks for all your help. I ended reordering the variables in my simulation so that year is first. It worked perfectly.